# I cannot access terminal app from desktop

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am totally new to Ubuntu. I have to use it for my research.

Gnome Terminal does not respond. I tried right clicking from files, "open in terminal" and that's also not working. Nothing pops up.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is still working.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal.
```

But I got stuck at `var/lib/dpkg/lock is read only`

So I tried

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

But I got this error, `abort force by user cannot remount /dev/sda1 is write-protect`

Sorry that I cannot copy all. I cannot copy from command prompt.

Comment: launch a new terminal just type this:         ctrl + alt + t

Answer (score 0):

As Scott mentioned in the question comments, the keyboard shortcut of Ctrl + Alt + T should normally launch a terminal window. Another way I can suggest is opening the applications menu and looking for alternate terminal programs.

When using Lubuntu (a derivative of Ubuntu using LXDE) I tend to find 2 - 4 various terminal programs available from the applications menu. I'm not sure if there's a similar case in the desktop edition of Ubuntu (I only run a server edition installation), but it's certainly worth looking.

It sounds like some of the issues you encountered could be caused by permissions. That would also be worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem is not with terminal, but rather with your storage device or permissions. Can it be that your harddrive is damaged? When you run `gnome-disks`, does it have any warning message on your device with system?

Answer (score 0):

To open a terminal : Use Crtl + Alt + T

To copy from terminal : Select the text and hit Crtl + Shift + C